# UIButton unrecognized selector sent to instance when using code in new ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, audio, uibutton

I've started building a very simple app which has two screens. The first has two UIbuttons. One button plays a random sound using the code below in my first view controller (ViewController.swift) and the other button modally presents a second screen.

On the second screen there are also two UIbuttons one to play another random sound and the other to go back to the first screen.

Playing a random sound on the first screen works perfectly.

For the second screen I have created a brand new ViewController called PageOneViewController.swift and made sure that the class is assigned correctly in IB. This second view controller contains a carbon copy clone of the code from the second page except with changes in names to avert conflict and confusuion. However any attempt to play a sound on this second page results in a Unrecognized Selector error and I cannot figure out why.

The error message is as follows:

```
2016-10-17 18:04:57.749 NewApp[28750:2719569] *** Terminating app     due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-    [NewApp.PageOneViewController buttonPressed2WithSender:]: unrecognized     selector sent to instance 0x7fe79070b8a0'
```

And it stops on this line (which I realise isn't much help):

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

I am connecting the buttons manually via the inspector and using 'Touch Up Inside" as the touch method.

I cannot get my head around this at all. In the good old Objective-C days I would run into this issue when I'd named a file incorrectly or one of the sound files was missing from the bundle but I've checked everything over and over again and cannot work out whats going on.

Code for ViewController.swift:

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainButton1: UIButton!

    var arrayOfSounds = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",     "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21",     "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33",     "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44",
                         "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51" ,     "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63",     "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75",     "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82"]
    var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer?

    func setupAudioPlayer(file: NSString, type: NSString){
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file as     String, ofType: type as String)
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
        do {
            try  audioPlayer =  AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
        } catch {
            print("Player not available")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject){
            let range: UInt32 = UInt32(arrayOfSounds.count)
            let number = Int(arc4random_uniform(range))

    self.setupAudioPlayer(arrayOfSounds[number], type: "wav")
    self.audioPlayer?.play()




}
}
```

Code for PageOneViewController.swift:

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class PageOneViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainButtonNew: UIButton!

    var arrayOfSounds = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",     "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21",     "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33",     "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44",
                         "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51" ,     "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63",     "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75",     "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82"]
    var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer?

    func setupAudioPlayer(file: NSString, type: NSString){
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file as     String, ofType: type as String)
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
        do {
            try  audioPlayer =  AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
        } catch {
            print("Player not available")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressedNew(sender: AnyObject){
            let range: UInt32 = UInt32(arrayOfSounds.count)
            let number = Int(arc4random_uniform(range))

    self.setupAudioPlayer(arrayOfSounds[number], type: "wav")
    self.audioPlayer?.play()




}
}
```

Comment: Double check everything is linked in interface builder.

Comment: Update your question with the complete and exact error message and point out the exact line causing the error.

Comment: Before playing audio file you need to do, player.prepareToPlay , and also use optional binding instead force unwrap the variables in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I still don't know exactly what caused this issue but a desperate attempt to fix it resulted in me updating to Swift 3 from 2.3, fixed the issue immediately.

Answer (score 1):

What may have happened is in storyboard something may have a double reference like a button referencing two IBOutlets or to two IBActions. You may have forgotten to remove a reference from them check their connections in the connection inspector or ctrl clicking on one. Have you tried placing print statements in your code or breakpoints to see exactly where it crashes?

Comment: I've disconnected and re-connected multiple times to make sure and everything is as it should be. As re: breakpoints. To be extra sure I set a break at every line in both ViewControllers. What's strange is that pressing that button does not cause a break anywhere in either ViewController. It goes straight to an exception.

Comment: maybe need to close the connection to the first AudioPlayer before accessing it again in the second view controller?